# Laravel: Change filename when uploading using store()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm uploading files and by default uploaded filename are set to `hashName()`. How can I set it to customized?

```
$uploadfiles = $request->file('file');

foreach ($uploadfiles as $key => $value) {

    $file = $value->store('public/fca_files');
    //Something like $value->store('public/fca_files','May 2, 2018 Report.xlsx');

    $file_name_before = $value->getClientOriginalName();
    $file_ext = $value->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name_after = $value->hashName();
    $file_size = $value->getClientSize();
...
```

Comment: use `$file->move('location',$file->getClientOriginalName());` to save file with custom name or maybe use `store` function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use storeAs() and pass the filename in the 2nd argument

```
$file = $value->storeAs('public/fca_files', 'Your filename');
```